# ApplicationContext.xml does not update env variables at target

Tags: spring, hibernate, datasource, applicationcontext

This is my code for ApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
                <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
                <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
                <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
                <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
                <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
                <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
                <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000" />
                <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3" />
                <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
            </bean>
```

My properties are defined in a file named **database.properties**

What changes do i need to make in the **parent pom.xml** to **convert the env variable** at **target runtime**

Can you please help or give me a proper suggestion or a link that could get me the name of database properties at runtime.
For eg
`database.driverName` should be updated to `jdbcDriver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my project had to respective `.properties` file, and my parent pom.xml was taking only .properties file. It was not able to fetch the other .properties file. The reason my variables were not getting updated at runtime. I maintained a `common.properties` file and added the path in `pom.xml`

Now i get the desired result

Answer (score 1):

```java
@Component
public class PropertyReloader {

    @Autowired
    private StandardEnvironment env;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate=5000)
    public void reloadProperties() throws IOException {
        MutablePropertySources ps = env.getPropertySources();
        Properties pr = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ApplicationContext.xml");
        pr.load(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        pr.replace("class path resource [ApplicationContext.xml]", new PropertiesPropertySource("class path resource [ApplicationContext.xml]", pr));
    }
}
```

This will update in every five seconds.

Comment: My parent pom.xml has env tag and the path specified in it defined, but on target the actual name isn't getting called.